# Build Error: The type javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be resolved

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

Getting build error:

```
The type javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage cannot be resolved.
```

It is indirectly referenced from required .class files.

How can I resolve this? Saw a similar question where it was suggested to add some jar.
But I'm using Maven.

Comment: This is part of Javamail. Download it, deploy it.

Comment: Hi Peter, Your message is lacking some information. e.g. what tries to send the mail in your case. But in maven you can simply use [javax mail](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api/1.6.2)

Answer (score 5):

Add this dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/javax.mail-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

this will add implementation of `javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage` to your classpath

Comment: That's great for compiling, assuming you're deploying to an app server that includes JavaMail (e.g., a Java EE app server).  If you're deploying to somewhere that doesn't already include a JavaMail implementation, you'll need the complete implementation jar file.  More details [here](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/#Download_JavaMail_Release).

Comment: Hi Bill! Thanks for clarification!

Comment: Didn't help for me

Answer (score 2):

I had encontered the same error message. In my case the reason was a mix of a new `jakarta.mail` (v2+) and an old `GreenMail` (v1.6).

You can either upgrade GreenMail or downgrade Jakarta.

Also make sure you don't have an old `javax.mail` as transitive dependency from an old other packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can still solve the problem by adding the javax.mail jar in the classpath.
You can download the jar here https://javaee.github.io/javamail/